# How to prevent python from making multiple individual scatter plots but produce single scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Multiple scatter plots** produced upon **not being** called. How can i rectify this problem?

```
while True:
    try:
        a=pickle.load(f)
        a1=a['result']
        a2=a['params']
        result=np.array([x for x in a1])
        params=np.array([[z,v] for z,v in a2.items()])
        par=params[3][1]
        precision=result[0]
        #print('precision:',precision,'|','parameters:',par)
        plt.scatter(par,precision,label='Precisionx-Sampling',color='k')
        plt.xlabel('phew')
        plt.ylabel('whep')
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()   
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Produces individual plots for (par,precision) in a sequence

Comment: move `plt.show()` to after of your while loop.

Comment: +1 @MasonCaiby `plt.show()` will output a new chart each time. Similarly `plt.xlabel` `plt.ylabel` and `plt.legend` can be moved outside the loop since you only need to call them once.

Comment: Hey Mason, Did you mean something like this  except \n EOFError:
\n      break
\n plt.show()

Comment: It seems to work now. Thank you Mason

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers. If no answer has completely answered your question please leave a comment with how it can be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.show()` opens a new chart every time it is called. You can also move everything that impacts the layout of the chart out of the `while` loop as well. This should work for you, but since I don't have your pickled files, I haven't tried it.

```
while True:
    try:
        a=pickle.load(f)
        a1=a['result']
        a2=a['params']
        result=np.array([x for x in a1])
        params=np.array([[z,v] for z,v in a2.items()])
        par=params[3][1]
        precision=result[0]
        #print('precision:',precision,'|','parameters:',par)
        plt.scatter(par,precision,label='Precisionx-Sampling',color='k')


    except EOFError:
        break

plt.xlabel('phew')
plt.ylabel('whep')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Why is this in a `while` loop though? `f` loops like it never changes, so you aren't changing `a`, which is how you produce the graphs. Is there some more code you removed from the loop to change which file you are loading?

Comment: I am loading a pickle file to extract some stored parameters to produce plots from them. I do not change anything in the above but use them.

Comment: So if you're just loading data from 1 pickle file why do you have it in a for loop? Also, did the above code answer your question?

Comment: I have multiple data that I'd like to read from the pickle file. The above help me sort out the problem. Thanks